# Rebinding Vim key in sexp-mappings-for-regular-people

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using Tim Pope's [Sexp Mappings For Regular People](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people)

I want to remap the slurp and barf commands that are currently bound to:  >) and <)   to: ctrl-alt right arrow and ctrl-alt left arrow -

I am using a Mac

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim's plugin doesn't allow further customization (and as the sexp-plugin defines *buffer-local* mappings, this isn't that trivial), so you have the following options:

1. Directly change `plugin/sexp.vim` from Tim. Normally, this is a bad idea, but as these just provide remappings that presumably are quite stable, it may be fine for you.
2. Write your own customization file, modeled after the one from Tim.

In any case, you'd need the following commands:

```
nmap <buffer> <C-A-Right>  <Plug>(sexp_emit_head_element)
nmap <buffer> <C-A-Left>  <Plug>(sexp_emit_tail_element)
```

Note that Ctrl + Alt + cursor keys may work in the GUI version, but probably not in terminal Vim.

Comment: I was afraid of that maybe I'll remap my cursive keys to be consistent with sexp-vim and teach my fingers to do the walking

Comment: I like this idea but instead using `<c-h>` and `<c-l>` which does work in a terminal.